# how to remove table row based on contents of one of the cells in the row using python?

Tags: python, html

I have html document with table like:

```
<tr>
<td width="3%"><input type="checkbox", name="chk"></td>
<td width="10%">101</td>
<td width="4%">Fix</td>
<td width="5%">2.00</td>
<td width="6%">09:28:03</td>
<td width="5%">5</td>
<td width="9%">6026866.421</td>
<td width="9%">6525118.804</td>
<td width="5%">149.124</td>
<td width="8%">3533692.676</td>
<td width="8%">1174580.462</td>
<td width="8%">5161083.095</td>
<td width="5%">0.009</td>
<td width="5%">0.016</td>
<td width="5%">2.14</td>
<td width="7%">07/09</td></tr>
<br>
<tr>
<td width="3%"><input type="checkbox", name="chk"></td>
<td width="10%">101</td>
<td width="4%">Fix</td>
<td width="5%">0.00</td>
<td width="6%">09:28:03</td>
<td width="5%">5</td>
<td width="9%">6026866.421</td>
<td width="9%">6525118.804</td>
<td width="5%">149.124</td>
<td width="8%">3533692.676</td>
<td width="8%">1174580.462</td>
<td width="8%">5161083.095</td>
<td width="5%">0.009</td>
<td width="5%">0.016</td>
<td width="5%">2.14</td>
<td width="7%">07/09</td></tr>
```

and so on....
I need to remove rows where the fourth cell content is '0.00' and leave
only these with '2.00' or maybe would be easier to remove only even rows.
what is the most simple way to achieve it using python?

Comment: funny as someone votes down rather than gives any answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Beautiful Soup (this is just a start, there's much to improve, like how to check for zero and you also have to make up your mind if you want to check the third or the fourth cell):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('yourhtml.html').read())
for tr in soup('tr'):
    if tr('td')[3].text == '0.00':
         tr.extract()
```

Comment: I have error with your example: if tr('td')[4].text == '0.00':
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), a python parser for HTML and XML.